how to type vue3 reactive object to be of a Type that need instanciation
I wanted to type a reactive object as follow:
const client = reactive<PublicClient>({})

but my linter complains:
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type {...
so I add Partial
const client = reactive<Partial<PublicClient>>({})

but it has the annoying side effect that forces me later on to check every properties are indeed defined otherwise I get:
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
the PublicClient type is rather complex and has many properties so it's not practicle to create a default object to instantiate it like:
reactive<PublicClient>(defaultPublicClient)

what would be best solution to properly type my client object?

It seems like both solutions you give are reasonable. Using a non-null assertion (!) to tell your linter that your object is defined might be annoying but you are wanting to initialize an empty object, so it /could/ be undefined, so your linter is just being helpful. Initializing with a default object also seems reasonable and better than your first solution.. why not just store it in another file if it's so complex?

I usually use interfaces to circumvent the linter issues. It is a bit cumbersome but works for me:
export interface ICard {
    name: String,
}

export default class Card implements ICard {
    private _name: String;

    constructor(name: String) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name(): String {
        return this._name;
    }
}

And then in the SFC to use in props:
const props = defineProps({
    card: { type: Object as PropType<ICard>, required: true },
});

